# Edit a CodeIgniter + AJAX multi-part form by showing all inputs to be changed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, codeigniter

#### Overview

This is my first time to create a complicated multi-part form with CodeIgniter.

I have a CodeIgniter multi-part form that relies on AJAX Post for submission (using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)). I preview the form after successful validation for the user to check if their answers are all okay. They can submit it to the database via a **Submit to database** button or an **Edit Form** button to go back and change whatever they want to check and the cycle begins again!

#### Problem

My multi-part form has **file inputs and dynamically added DOM elements** (for example, a user can declare multiple addresses so four textboxes will be added via JavaScript) and I want these to be intact one Edit is hit.

I have several methods to attack but none works so far:

1. **Simulate the browser back button** - seems effective but I remembered that my controller's `index()` loads the new form view so it's useless.
2. **Take all the data from the preview form, put them in an array, carry the array to the `index()`, count the occurrences of the dynamically added element and just show all of them** - this one is pretty tedious and complicated for me. Plus I'm not sure if carrying all the `$_POST` data to an array is safe but it's the best one I can think of.

**Do you guys have any suggestions or *better* methods to attack this kind of process?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to implement a solution based around your second option - and yes, it is tedious, but there's no other way of doing it. Some things to remember:

You need to think of a concise way to store your data. Addresses should be stored as one array element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="addresses[1][street]">
<input type="text" name="addresses[1][city]">
<input type="text" name="addresses[1][county]">
```

This will allow you to iterate succinctly over your data structure for front-end presentation:

```
<? foreach ($data['addresses'] as $number => $address): ?>
   <? foreach ($address as $address_item => $value): ?>
      <input type="text" name="addresses[<?=$number?>][<?=$address_item?>]" value="<?=$value?>">
   <? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This will provide full control over your layouts, reducing the amount of JavaScript you'll have to use to stock your DOM (which is not as quick or efficient).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I really have to do it the hard way then :D